# How to make a text right aligned?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I have two texts in a column and I want the second to be right aligned:

```
first
                                                 second
```

How can I do that?

I've tried wrapping the second text in a Row or a Column, to no awail. This is what I have so far:

```
    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
        Text(text = "first")
        Column(horizontalAlignment = Alignment.End) {
            Text(text = "second")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try as follows:

```
Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
    Text(text = "first")
    Text(text = "second", modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.End))
}
```

And your code snippet didn't work because the inner column's width was effectively set to 'wrap content.' Adding `modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()` there would have led to the result you expected.